# How can i avoid the facebook permission in post sharing. from the app

Tags: facebook, post, permissions, sharing

How can i avoid the facebook permission in post sharing.when i sharing a post using facebook app from my website the interface asks the permission for it.how can i avoid it.

Comment: If you want to make a post in the name of the user via API, then you need the user to login to your app and grant it appropriate permission first. If you don’t want that, use the Share or the Feed dialog – those leave full control in the hands of the user, and don’t need any permissions.

Comment: Sir   Can you explain.

Comment: Go read the documentation please.

Answer (score -1):

yeah its the same issue for me also
how to revoke the facebook permission